# Unable to change Postgresql data directory with systemd service overrides on Ubuntu 22

Tags: systemd, postgresql

I am trying to change the data directory that Postgres uses to look for its configuration files.

I have a fresh update of Ubuntu 22 and newly installed Postgresql@15.

In order to maintain version control over my Postgres configuration files, I've copied over the default configs to a new data directory in my server-configs repo, `/usr/local/apps/server-configs/configs/postgres/postgres_data/`.

Postgresql installs its service files to these paths: (*/lib, not /etc*):

```
/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@15-main.service
```

Via `sudo systemctl edit postgresql` and `sudo systemctl edit postgresql@15-main.service`, I have added the following service environment variable assignment to both locations:

```
[Service]
Environment=
Environment=PGDATA=/usr/local/apps/server-configs/configs/postgres/postgres_data/
```

(*The double `Environment` declarations may be incorrect. In troubleshooting this, I read somewhere that they must be set to clear whatever was there before.*)

In turn this created 2 override files:

```
postgresql.service.d/override.conf
postgresql@15-main.service.d/override.conf
```

I then did both a daemon-reload and restarted Postgres, just for kicks.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Finally to check if the new data directory was picked up by Postgres, I connected to the database and checked via this method:

```
sudo -iu postgres
psql
postgres@logs:~$ psql

psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg22.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW config_file;
               config_file               
-----------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

I've been reading lots of walk throughs that describe this as more or less the correct way to solve this. But no matter what I've been trying, the config file still points at the installed one and not the version in my `server-configs` repo.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: 1. why not just use [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/)? keeping a revision history of config files in git (or your preferred RCS) is precisely what it's for. It's available packaged for most distros  2. Why are you trying to do this via systemd rather than editing postgresql's config files?  Do you need to run two or more instances of postgres? if so: a) why? postgres's roles allow a database server to be shared without giving all users access to all databases; b) if you do need it, remember to run each instance on a separate IP address and/or port.

Comment: BTW, I know that on Debian at least, `etckeeper` comes with integration scripts for the package manager (apt) which cause it to commit /etc before installing/upgrading package(s) and again afterwards.  I expect that similar scripts are available for .rpm distros.  It also has a daily autocommit cron job, in case you forget to manually commit any changes to /etc.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue and it turns out I had a shadow postgres installed alongside my manually compiled version. The shadow postgres was installed with apt using postgres-contrib-15. My systemd script below was actually starting the shadow postgres using a global postgresql.conf

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
Documentation=man:postgres(1)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=postgres
Environment=PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
ExecStart=/usr/lib/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*edit* to fix the issue I simply removed postgres-contrib-15 with `sudo apt remove postgres-contrib-15`

Comment: So, how do you *fix* the problem?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.